# Clipboard: copy paste to/from multiple buffers

Tags: linux, copy-paste, clipboard

I would like to copy and paste using multiple buffers.
E.g. ctr+c+$n copies to a buffer$n, then ctr+v+$n pastes the content from the buffer$n where $n is a number on the keyboard from 0 to 9. Is there any tool in Linux for it? How could I achieve that?